# Find alphabets from integer value (like 123AB456 - filter these type of records using XSLT code)

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing some XSLT code and trying to filter out records like '123456A' and this XSLT output should be the input for a SOAP request.

How can I filter these partial alphanumeric records from the XML?

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Try showing some input, the expected output, and the code you have so far - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them out with a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="val[not(translate(.,'0123456789','----------') = substring('--------------------------',1,string-length(.)))]" />
```

Here, `val` is the element's name and every `val` which does not completely consist of digits `0` to `9` is ignored/filtered out (until a certain length).

Comment: If that is indeed the goal, then surely `[string-length(translate(.,'0123456789','')) > 0]` would be both simpler and without any limit on the length?